# Generated Text Fields Position

Tags: java, android

Is there a way I can position generated text fields to my layout programmatically. Here is what the generated text field currently looks like:

[image]

Here is the code I have for generating these two fields:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingButton);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(AddSongActivity.this);
        EditText artist = new EditText(AddSongActivity.this);
        EditText songTitle = new EditText(AddSongActivity.this);
        artist.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        songTitle.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.addView(artist);
        linearLayout.addView(songTitle);
        ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.add_song_layout)).addView(linearLayout);
    }
});
```

Here is the add song layout that goes along with the above code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/add_song_layout"
    tools:context="com.example.android.playmymusicapp3.AddSongActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ScrollView>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingButton"
        android:src="@mipmap/plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick ="onClick"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary">

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:text="Add songs to your event..."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Artist"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way where I can tell Android to take those two generated text fields and place them exactly like the ones I have that are centered?

Answer (score 0):

You should try new Constraint Layout. You can really good position your elements.

[ConstraintLayout Tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html

Example:

> The following code configures a constraint set in which the left-hand
>   side of a Button view is connected to the right-hand side of an
>   EditText view with a margin of 70dp:

```
set.connect(button1.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 
    editText1.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 70);
```

You can do the same for TOP and BOTTOM values.

Comment: Maybe could you provide an example of how I could do that in my code... p.s non of the links are working.

Comment: The first and the second links are tutorials. If you like that, you can see in the third link how to implement it in your code. It will take you several hours, but you'll see that it is a powerful concept.

Comment: Thanks! I will try these outs